# RewriteRule in Apache to rewrite URL not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL which is obtained currently is localhost:9004/index.jsp/accountno=10&usernane=abc&password=123 
I need to get localhost:9004/index.jsp 
I have used Rewrite to change the URL from localhost:9004/index.jsp/accountno=10&usernane=abc&password=123 to localhost:9004/index.jsp

```
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /index.jsp last
```

but I'm facing the error in this line what changes should be made in the code so that the URL does not contain query strings and i obtain localhost:9004/index.jsp

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the tool you use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html It lists the flag `QSD` which is what you are looking for. You will lose that information though, not sure if that is what you want...

Comment: So how should I use rewrite rule in this case

Comment: What exactly doesn't the documentation answer?

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneous spotting: you matching pattern tries to match a leading slash. So an absolute path. Yet you say you implement this rule inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). The documentation clearly points out that a `RewriteRule` operates on *relative paths* in that case. Which is why your pattern will never match.

Remove the trailing slash or make it optional for better portability of your rule to make the pattern match:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.jsp/ /index.jsp [QSD,END]
```

However as already written in the comments: although this answers your question it obviously removes the additional parameters. You will lose them. I doubt that is what you actually want...

Also I fail to see the point in this: you could just ignore those additional arguments on the server side anyway...

This would be a variant that performs an external redirection instead so that the URL visualized inside the browser gets changed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?index\.jsp/ /index.jsp [R_301,QSD,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).